# Cannot create foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a foreign key in my `user_details` table.
I have 2 foreign keys in my `user_details` table, one is the `user_id` referencing to the user id in the main user table created by Sentinel. I also have a countries table where I want to set the `country_of_origin` field to the country numeric code from the countries table. but every time I execute my migration I get the following error

```
"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
```

Schema for my country table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
        $table->charset = 'utf8';
        $table->integer('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('alpha_2');
        $table->string('alpha_3');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```

the id field is the ISO 3166-1 numeric country code, not an autoincrementing id for the row. Also, the data for this table is feed from a JSON file using a seeder.

Schema for my user details table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id',true);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('date_of_birth');
        $table->integer('country_of_origin')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('contact_number');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
    Schema::table('user_details', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('country_of_origin')->references('id')->on('countries');
    });
}
```

The migration to create the country table is executed first before the the execution of the user_details migration.

if I remove `$table->foreign('country_of_origin')->references('id')->on('countries');` I dont get any errors. I have also tried `$table->integer('country_of_origin');` but i still get the same error.

**Solution**
the issue was because of the name of the id field in the countries table but in reality, it wasn't an autoincrementing col rather had fixed value based on the seeded data.

I changed my Schema as follows 
Country Schema

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
        $table->charset = 'utf8';
        $table->increments('id',true);
        $table->integer('num_id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('alpha_2');
        $table->string('alpha_3');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```

Added an extra field for the autoincrementing id and stored the SO 3166-1 numeric country code in the num_id field

in the User details table, just changed the following

```
 $table->foreign('country_of_origin')->references('num_id')->on('countries');
```

Comment: Is the column `id` on table `users` unsigned / integer as well?

Comment: @garre yes.as i said above ` $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` doesnt give me any errors but the line after that does

Comment: Seems like `id` on `countries` is not unsigned.

Comment: @jackowski I tried adding "$table->integer('id')->unsigned();" on the countries table but it still fails

Comment: I'm seeding the data in the countries table from a JSON file. would that cause issues?

Comment: Remove unsigned() from this line -> `$table->integer('country_of_origin')->unsigned();`

Comment: @Rits tried it, but getting the same error

Comment: Then take unsigned to countries id `$table->integer('id')->unsigned();`

Comment: you need auto increment your countries id??

Comment: @Rits yes that was the error, I needed an autoincrementing id field. I have updated my question with the solution

Comment: :) awesome buddy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` in `countries` table must be a primary key

Comment: +1 I realised my mistake from this comment. I shall edit my question above to have the solution. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
        $table->charset = 'utf8';
        $table->integer('countryid')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('alpha_2');
        $table->string('alpha_3');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm seeding the data for this table from a JSON file. The id is not the column id but the ISO 3166-1 numeric country code.

Comment: changed the answer, if you still getting the error after changing this, could you post the error